# Printf in C with using sleep not working

Tags: c

why my program NOT printf ?

First asleep and then writes , but he should do it the other way round..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

void sleepMilliSecond(long milliSecondInput) {
#ifdef _WIN32
    Sleep(milliSecondInput); // v milliSecondach
#else
    usleep(pollingDelay * 1000); //microsekundy -> milisekundy
#endif
}



int main(int argc, char** argv) {  
    printf("start sleep");    
    sleepMilliSecond(1000);   //sleep 1s 
    printf("stop sleep");
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Output of program is: sleep and then he write start sleep stop sleep, WHY?

**EDIT:**
Working solution is:

```
printf("start sleep");    
fflush(stdout);
sleepMilliSecond(10000); 
printf("stop sleep");
```

Comment: For me no, because he write to console "START SLEEP" after sleeping interval :(

Comment: `printf` is buffered. try `fflush(stdout)` after the first `printf`

Comment: stdout is line buffered, you want to add a `\n` to print it immediately

Comment: pollingDelay isn't defined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`printf` is buffered I/O. To force the buffer to be written to output you can call `fflush` as so:

```
printf("start sleep");
fflush(stdout);
sleepMilliSecond(1000);   //sleep 1s 
printf("stop sleep");
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not flushing "stop sleep" and "start sleep" it's still in the buffer. Add a \n to the end:

> printf("start sleep\n");
>   printf("stop sleep\n");

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant not working fflush(stdout) help me.